# PySpark Mllib Predict all rows in DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark Streaming to get batches of JSON readings from Kafka.  The resulting batch is converted from an RDD to a dataframe.

My goal is to do a classification on each row of this dataframe so I am using a VectorAssembler to create the features that will be passed to the model:

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(rdd.context)
rawReading = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd)
sensorReadings = rawReading.selectExpr("actual.y AS yaw","actual.p AS pitch", "actual.r AS roll")
assembler = VectorAssembler(
        inputCols=["yaw", "pitch", "roll"],
        outputCol="features")
sensorReadingsFinal = assembler.transform(sensorReadings)
sensorReadingsFinal.show()
+---+-----+----+-----------------+
|yaw|pitch|roll|         features|
+---+-----+----+-----------------+
| 18| 17.5| 120|[18.0,17.5,120.0]|
| 18| 17.5| 120|[18.0,17.5,120.0]|
| 18| 17.5| 120|[18.0,17.5,120.0]|
| 18| 17.5| 120|[18.0,17.5,120.0]|
| 18| 17.5| 120|[18.0,17.5,120.0]|
+---+-----+----+-----------------+
```

I have a Random Forest model that I have trained previously.

```
loadedModel = RandomForestModel.load(sc, "MyRandomForest.model")
```

My question is, How can I make a prediction on each row in the dataframe before inserting the whole thing into a database?

I was initially thinking about doing something like this...

```
prediction = loadedModel.predict(sensorReadings.features)
```

but I'm realizing that since the dataframe has multiple rows, I will need to somehow add a column and do the prediction row by row.  Maybe I'm going about this all wrong?

The final dataframe that I'd like is something like this:

```
+---+-----+----+-----------------+
|yaw|pitch|roll|       Prediction|
+---+-----+----+-----------------+
| 18| 17.5| 120|              1  |
| 18| 17.5| 120|              1  |
| 18| 17.5| 120|              1  |
| 18| 17.5| 120|              1  |
| 18| 17.5| 120|              1  |
+---+-----+----+-----------------+
```

At which point I will save it to a database:

```
sensorReadingsFinal.write.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb", "SensorReadings", properties=connectionProperties)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark ML, the method for getting predictions from data is called `transform`, so I guess you are looking for this:

```
prediction = loadedModel.transform(sensorReadings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing to resolve this:

```
# Convert DStream RDD's to DataFrame and run SQL query
sqlContext = SQLContext(rdd.context)
if rdd.isEmpty() == False:
    rawReading = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd)
    sensorReadings = rawReading.selectExpr("actual.y AS yaw","actual.p AS pitch", "actual.r AS roll")
    assembler = VectorAssembler(
                inputCols=["yaw","pitch","roll"], # Must be in same order as what was used to train the model.  Testing using only pitch since model has limited dataset.
                outputCol="features")
    sensorReadings = assembler.transform(sensorReadings)

    # Create a new dataFrame of predictions and readingID
    predictions = loadedModel.predict(sensorReadings.map(lambda x: x.features))
    predictionsDF = sensorReadings.map(lambda x: x.readingID).zip(predictions).toDF(["readingID","positionID"])
    
    # Join the prediction dataFrame back to the sensorReadings dataFrame.  Drop the duplicate readingID column.
    combinedDF = sensorReadings.join(predictionsDF, sensorReadings.readingID == predictionsDF.readingID).drop(predictionsDF.readingID)
    
    # Drop the feature vector column
    combinedDF = combinedDF.drop("features")
    
    combinedDF.show()
```

I basically created a new dataFrame of just the feature vectors and readingID and then joined it back to the original dataFrame.

This may not be the most elegant solution so if someone can suggest something better, please do.